# XCode adding header files to Build Phases automatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am adding an Objective-C class to my iOS project in XCode.
Xcode creates me a header file and implementation file, so far so good.
I do my implementation and build the app. XCode gives me a warning, for example:

warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/EnterMobile/OrganizationListService.h' of type sourcecode.objj.h for architecture i386

It automatically adds the header file to my Build Phases. 
I can remove it manually, but it seems to do it for every Class I am adding. :(

Is there a setting or something why it is adding the header files to my Build Phases?